# Hold issue for microcontroller question

Tags: discussion

Any thoughts on [THIS QUESTION](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112878/need-help-with-selecting-right-microcontroller-homemade-smart-watch), closed as a shopping question?  It brings up a few issues for me. First, it doesn't look like a shopping question to me.  There may be some good reasons to close it or DV, but a request on picking the appropriate microcontroller looks like a bread and butter question.

Second, if it needed to be closed as a shopping question, I'm not sure why it simply wasn't left up to the community to handle. This doesn't seem to fit into the "moderator as exception handler" model that's been so successful here.

Perhaps the axe is being wielded a bit heavily here?  If not, that suggests that community moderation isn't doing what it should, and that would be an appropriate matter for a meta discussion.

Comment: No, Nick was not being excessively heavy-handed on this one; it really is a poor question for EE.SE. He could've left it for the community moderators to handle, but sometimes it's better to nip these in the bud.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with that one being closed quickly, while I'm open to more specific product selection questions that one has quite a few problems:

- Very opinion based and I'm sure they'd be many different and equally valid opinions on whether a AVR / PIC / MSP430 / ARM etc was best / easiest to use. Likewise things like "easy learning curve" and "no complex programming" are open to opinion as well.
- Terms like "low power" and "quite a bit of memory" are vague and both probably rely as much on good programming as microcontroller selection. The fact there's no description of what the device should be capable of also doesn't help.
- There's no mention of if this is some sort of prototype and the user's hardware experience. For example would they be happy with a BGA device recommendation?

I think the longer it was open was just a chance for it for everyone to recommend their favorite micro and other "helpful hints" without any single answer being correct or complete enough to really help them or anyone else in the future.

As mentioned in comments at this stage of their project idea it's really a better question for chat or a forum where brainstorming ideas are welcome. Either that or hiring a consultant under NDA if they really don't want to disclose information on the overall idea.

Comment: I completely agree, and would hope that the poster would get a more accurate close message the "recommendation for specific product" message if it were closed by the community.  Maybe "primarily opinion", or something else that would result in the right edit to make it a good question.

Answer (score 0):

"pick me a μC" questions are routinely closed on EE.SE .  Here's my rationale for closing that particular one :

- This is shopping question.  It fits the formal definition.  The O.P. have even specified the price range.
- The long term value of the question is not very high.  New models of microcontrollers come out every year.  So, the landscape is changing.  Besides, the next such fellow will need different specs.  128x128 memory array instead of 96x96, Ethernet instead of USB.
- The question is naive, which is an aggravating factor.  The O.P. is looking for wonders in the land of Internet, and he thinks that there is a royal road.  (He should be looking for a serious book, or a training course, or a sensei.  That is, if he's actually committed to his project, albeit naive.)
- "pick me a μC" questions often trigger opinion-based discussion, where respondents advocate for a μC that they particularly like.  This is sometimes called *microcontroller religious wars*.  Novice's naivete tends to fuel this.

*Post factum* the question was nominated for reopening.  But nobody is rushing to vote for reopening.  It's been 24h.

Comment: I have no trouble with this being closed, other than I think the reason wasn't quite accurate and that it was closed by a moderator, bypassing a capable community.  Some diamond moderator candidate once said  "The instantly binding vote will take some getting used to. I have some experience with community moderation. I think that community moderation works very well on EE.SE. I will not interfere with that. For instance, I’ll somewhat cool down my enthusiasm towards Close and Reopen queues, at least in the beginning."